# Increasing performance in file manipulation

Tags: performance, haskell, functional-programming, bytestring

I have a file which contains a matrix of numbers as following:

```
0 10 24 10 13 4 101 ...
6 0 52 10 4 5 0 4 ...
3 4 0 86 29 20 77 294 ...
4 1 1 0 78 100 83 199 ...
5 4 9 10 0 58 8 19 ...
6 58 60 13 68 0 148 41 ...
. .
.   .
.     .
```

What I am trying to do is sum each row and output the sum of each row to a new file (with the sum of each row on a new line).

I have tried doing it in Haskell using ByteStrings, but the performance is 3 times a slow as the python implementation.  Here is the Haskell implementation:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

-- This function is for summing a row
sumrows r = foldr (\x y -> (maybe 0 (*1) $ fst <$> (B.readInt x)) + y) 0 (B.split ' ' r)

-- This function is for mapping the sumrows function to each line
sumfile f = map (\x -> (show x) ++ "\n") (map sumrows (B.split '\n' f)) 

main = do
  contents <- B.readFile "telematrix"
  -- I get the sum of each line, and then pack up all the results so that it can be written
  B.writeFile "teleDensity" $ (B.pack . unwords) (sumfile contents)
  print "complete"
```

This takes about 14 seconds for a 25 MB file.

Here is the python implemenation

```
fd = open("telematrix", "r")
nfd = open("teleDensity", "w")

for line in fd: 
  nfd.write(str(sum(map(int, line.split(" ")))) + "\n")

fd.close()
nfd.close()
```

This takes about 5 seconds for the same 25 MB file.

Any suggestions on how to increase the Haskell implementation?

Comment: Could you link to the file? On my computer your Haskell program runs 4 times faster than the Python one with a random 1000 x 1000 matrix (which is 13 Mb).

Comment: Here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5nhttzeytkxzmwm/telematrix?dl=0

Comment: I think I might have figured out why it was so slow.  I was using runhaskell instead of compiling it with ghc and then running it.

Comment: How does `ghc -O2` perform, then?

Comment: @abden003 If it turns out it was indeed caused just by `runhaskell`, please consider adding it as your own answer (and accept it later) so that the question is marked as resolved.

Comment: You should use `foldl' (+) 0` to sum integers, not `foldr (+) 0` (you've manually fused this with another loop, but I hope you see what I mean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for the poor performance was because I was using runhaskell instead of first compiling and then running the program.  So I switched from:

```
runhaskell program.hs
```

to

```
ghc program.hs

./program
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that he problem was that I was compiling and running the program with runhaskell as opposed to using ghc and then running the program.  By compiling first and then running, I increased performance to 1 second in Haskell

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I would bet your first bottleneck is in the `++` on strings in `sumfile`, which is destructuring the left operand each time and rebuilding it. Instead of appending `"\n"` to the end, you could replace the `unwords` function call with `unlines`, which does exactly what you want it to here. That should get you a nice little speed boost.

A more minor nitpick is that the `(*1)` in the `maybe` function is unneeded. Using `id` there would be more efficient, since `(*1)` wastes a multiplication operation, but that's no more than a few processor cycles.

Then finally, I have to ask why you're using `ByteString`'s here. `ByteString`'s store string data efficiently as an array, like traditional strings in a more imperative language. However, what you're doing here involves splitting the string and iterating over the elements, which are operations that linked lists would be suited for. I would honestly recommend using the traditional `[Char]` type in this case. That `B.split` call may be what's ruining you, since it has to take the entire line and copy it into separate arrays of the split form, whereas the `words` function for linked lists of characters simply splits the linked structure off at a few points.

Comment: `B.split` doesn't copy data, it returns slices. `ByteString` is definitely much faster than lists for the OP's task. Also, the `++` in `sumfile` is a one-off small O(n) cost per line that shouldn't affect the total runtime much.

Comment: I'm quite sure using `ByteString` and `B.split` is ok and actually helps performance. The library is smart not to copy the arrays, it creates splices pointing to the original piece of data. In particular the documentation for [`split`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:split) says:

> As for all splitting functions in this library, this function does not copy the substrings, it just constructs new ByteStrings that are slices of the original.